# Origin of Latin Non-Finite Verbal Endings

Tags: historical-linguistics, morphology, latin

I'm wondering about the origins of the various non-finite verbal endings in Latin.

My understanding so far of their PIE origins:

- Infinitives:

  - Present Active: -s-ey (dative of an s-stem verbal noun)
  - Perfect Active: no idea
  - Present Passive: thematic genitive either on bare stem or s-stem depending on conjugation?
- Participles:

  - Present Active: -nt-s, other branches have o-grade in thematic verbs
  - Future Active: no idea
  - Perfect Passive: -t-os
  - Future Passive: related to the gerund?
- Verbal Nouns:

  - Gerund: presumably related to the present active participle, but the voicing is odd
  - Supine: -tu-s

Is anyone aware of further information on any of these?

Comment: I'm aware this may also be suited to latin se, but as it is primarily concerned with historical linguistics I think it's better suited to here

Comment: The perfect active is the same -se as amā-se (> amāre), vel-se (> velle), es-se, no?

Comment: Sihler (1995:610ff.) likens the present passive to Vedic infinitives based on datives of root nouns (_yujé_ < _*i̯ug-éi̯_, _rucé_ < _*luk-éi̯_) and says that the _-r-_ was inserted later by analogy with the actives where applicable, e.g., act. _*amāye-si_ vs pass. _*amāye-ī_ → _*amāye-si_ vs _*amāye-sī_. In cases like _*lege-si_ vs _*leg-ī_, apparently the parallel was too weak for the analogy to function. @Draconis But with something additional to account for the geminate s.

Comment: The Latin perfect stem had four origins and four shapes -- reduplicative (_dedi_), sigmatic (_visi_), u (_audivi_), and long vowel (_vīdi_). Plus plenty of consonant gradation and vowel change, like _vinco/vici_ or _ago/egi_.

Comment: @jlawler The _stems_, yes; but this is asking about the markers for the infinite forms, not the stems they’re attached to.

Comment: @Draconis that was my thought, but there's another suffix between it and the stem. It's not simply an aorist s either as in the third conjugation we have -isse presumably reflecting something like -es-se rather than the -s-se we'd expect from a sigmatic aorist with the same ending

Comment: @jlawler Janus is correct that I'm interested in the endings rather than stems. I've clarified the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally found sources for those options here that don't have completely transparent parallels and that don't really require explantion.

- **Infinitives**:

  - **Present Active**: per Weiss 2021, this is either a locative or "directive" of a neuter s-stem, either: **-si* or **-sa*
  - **Perfect Active**: Weiss says this consists of the -is- formant also seen in the pluperfect subjunctive and the -se component seen in the active indicative, so also either a location or "directive" of a neuter s-stem: **-is-si* or **-is-sa*
  - **Present Passive**: Weiss argues (on the basis of some alternative forms in -Vrier cf laudārier "to be praised") this consists of an earlier -ii̯V, comparing to the Vedic instrumental gerund in -ya/-yā. That Sanskrit form would suggest an i-stem masculine or feminine (or I guess a neuter where the -n- failed to be inserted to avoid collision of the vowels), a PIE instrumental of an i-stem would be: **-s-i-h₁* (or **-s-y-eh₁* if the ending was stressed)
- **Participles**:

  - **Present Active**: an nt-stem: **-nt-s*
  - **Future Active**: per Fortson this is a ro-derivative of the instrumental of the supine in -tu-: **-tu-h₁-r-os*
  - **Perfect Passive**: an o/eh₂-stem: **-t-os*
  - **Future Passive (aka Gerundive)**: per Jasanoff 2006, this goes back to an extension of the present active participle as an o/eh₂-stem: **-nt-in-os*
- **Verbal Nouns**:

  - **Gerund**: Jasanoff argues this is a secondary substantive use of the Future Passive (Gerundive) Participle, it's an o-stem: **-nt-in-om*
  - **Supine**: a u-stem: **-tu-s*

Weiss, Michael. 2021. Outline of the Historical and Comparative Grammar of Latin. Second edition. Ann Arbor: Beech Stave Press

Fortson, Benjamin W. IV. 2007. The origin of the Latin future active participle.

Jasanoff, J. H. 2006. The Origin of the Latin Gerund and Gerundive: A New Proposal

Comment: Weiss cites both the other sources used here when discussing the relevant formations and that was where I found the Fortson paper, but I'd actually found the Jasanoff one separately at an earlier date